# making my player sprite land on top of my platform sprite

Tags: c#, xna

in my XNA game(im fairly new to XNA by the way) i would like to have my player sprite land on top of a platform. i have a player sprite class that inherits from my regular sprite class, and the regular sprite class for 
basic non playable sprite stuff such as boxes, background stuff, and platforms. However, i am unsure how to implement a way to make my player sprite land on a platform.

My player Sprite can jump and move around, but i dont know where and how to check to see if it is on top of my platform sprite.

My player sprites jump method is here

```
 private void Jump()
    {

        if (mCurrentState != State.Jumping)
        {

            mCurrentState = State.Jumping;


            mStartingPosition = Position;

            mDirection.Y = MOVE_UP;

            mSpeed = new Vector2(jumpSpeed, jumpSpeed);

        }

    }
```

mStartingPosition is player sprites starting position of the jump, and Position is the player sprites current position. I would think that my code for checking to see whether my player sprite is on top of my platform sprite. I am unsure how to reference my platform sprite inside of the playersprite class and inside of the jump method.

i think it should be something like this

```
   //platformSprite.CollisonBox would be the rectangle around the platform, but im not 
    //sure how to check to see if player.Position is touching any point     
    //on platformSprite.CollisionBox
if(player.Position == platformSprite.CollisionBox)
    {
        player.mDirection = 0;

    }
```

Again im pretty new to programming and XNA, and some of this logic i dont quite understand so any help on any of it would be greatly appreciated:D

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If player.Position is a Point and CollisionBox is a Rectangle, you could use

```
if (platformSprite.CollisionBox.Contains (player.Position))
```

Comment: player.Position is a vector2 object, is there anyway to cast a vector2 object to a Point object? is that possible?

Comment: @Stone: you can create a new `Point` using the `Vector2.X` and `Vector2.Y`.  `Point myPoint = new Point(playerPosition.X, playerPosition.Y);`

Comment: use the reverse quote. on my keyboard it's the key on the left of number 1. Shift it because ~.

Answer (score 1):

I was playing around with something like this just a few days ago.
What you're calling a CollisionBox I called a BoundingBox.  A BoundingBox is a `Rectangle` which represents the area occupied by the sprite.

You'll probably find it helpful to define a BoundingBox for your sprites instead of just using their position.

You can easily test for the collision of Rectangles  using the following code:

```
if (player.BoundingBox.Intersects(platform.BoundingBox)
{
    // handle collision here...
}
```

For this to work, make sure that the `X` and `Y` coordinates of your BoundingBox are correctly reflecting your sprite's position.

Comment: ok ill have to to try the bounding box thing out later tonight. Also, would i have to initialize my platformSprite object inside of the player constructor? right now i initialize everything in the game1 class, and am confused on how to reference the platform sprite from the player class, would i just add a "Sprite platform;" to the top of my playe class?

Comment: i got the bounding box set up, but im still trying to figure out how to get an instance of platformSprite from within the player class. I guess i dont have enough programming savvy to figure this out lol. Im creating both my player and my platformSprite within the Game1 class.

Comment: im going to try and make a static platformSprite class and see how that works, i tried setting the object as static in the declaration of it at the top of the Game1 class but its still out of scope i guess.

Comment: ok the static platformSprite class allowed me to compile, but it seems my bounding boxes arent working as intented. gotta figure that out now :(

Comment: Hrm, maybe consider restructuring your code a bit.  How about creating a class to handle all the physics in your game?  This class could keep a list of sprites to update and a reference to the current map.

When you create a sprite that needs to be monitored for collisions, you'd just need to add it to your Physics class and it would take care of everything.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the [Platformer Starter Kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd254918%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx). It includes this as well as detecting when the player is touching an enemy, collecting gems, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The answer about BoundingBox is right, but IMHO it is easier to use Rectangle if you are making a 2D game rather than BoundingBox, wich is designed for a 3D one.

Anyway both objects have intersection / collision test methods that takes Vector2 or Point as parameter.

Now you have to have a box for your player, and a box for your platform. If one collide with the other, you have to check from where (the player can hit the platform from up, down, left, right, or maybe up & left on the left up corner).

If the player is on top of the platform, then just stop his fall, probably by setting his Y-speed component to 0.

Maybe you will need the player to go through the platform when jumping (player hit from bottom) but not when falling (player hit from top).